# Google Maps API - Offset the center point to ensure marker and infowindow are visible

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, google-maps-markers, infowindow

I have the following code to zoom into a google map and show an infowindow when you click on a marker...

```
google.maps.event.addListener(marker, "click", function () {
    infowindow.setContent(this.html);
    infowindow.open(map, this);
    map.setCenter(this.position);
    if(map.getZoom() < 10 || map.getZoom() > 10) {
        map.setZoom(10);
    }
});
```

However, the map size is based on the users browser window size and sometimes - when the map is not tall because of the browser window size - the infowindow disappears off the top. What I want to do is center the marker and infowindow rather than just the marker.

Any ideas?

Comment: Why not just `if(map.getZoom() != 10) { ... `? Anyway.. is that not just default Google Maps, that it centers the marker AND the infowindow?

Comment: Good point @putvande... I'd disabled autopan elsewhere in my code from a previous version of the project. Removing this fixes the problem. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You could get the height of your infowindow, then pan the map down half that amount.

```
map.panBy(0, info_window_height / 2);
```

If having the marker/infowindow in the center of the map isn't a strict requirement, also look at a SmartInfoWindow demo: http://gmaps-samples-v3.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/smartinfowindow/smartinfowindow.html